# how to open youtube app from android application

Tags: android, android-intent

i have **youtube** button which will open a **particular** **channel** for that i want it to open in **youtube** **application** in order to access a channel from my application.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW , Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCRmoG8dTnv0B7y9uoocikLw"));
context.startActivity(intent);
```

**But it is opening in browser**.

Comment: try this startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("url")));

Comment: @Rohit that is exactly the same code as the OP?

Comment: try this android.intent.action.VIEW

Answer (score 10):

You should explicitly send it to youtube. You can do this by specifing the package:

```
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.android.youtube","com.google.android.youtube.PlayerActivity"));
```

Also note that you should also check if youtube is installed!

```
Intent intent = new Intent(
    Intent.ACTION_VIEW , 
    Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCRmoG8dTnv0B7y9uoocikLw"));
intent.setComponent(new ComponentName("com.google.android.youtube","com.google.android.youtube.PlayerActivity"));

PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
List<ResolveInfo> infos = manager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
if (infos.size() > 0) {
     context.startActivity(intent);
}else{
     //No Application can handle your intent
}
```

Comment: Note also, you will probably want to catch an ActivityNotFoundException around your startActivity call to fall back to the browser youtube player.

Comment: Correct @elimirks, I've added it to my answer.

Comment: I dont think this is the correct approach, Majorly because the packaname/activity names can be updated/changed by the application provider. All application should be started by correct intent-actions. Though, this might not cause any immediate problem, but can break easily. (Depends on Google...)

Comment: True, but the other solution would be to set Youtube as the main handler of such URLs.

Answer (score 6):

I found this to be a simple way to do this (assumes you already checked that YouTube is installed):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/**YOURCHANNEL**"));
intent.setPackage("com.google.android.youtube");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanks for the package name of `YouTube`

Answer (score 2):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setData(Uri.parse(urlStr));
startActivity(intent);
```

**urlStr** is the url of your desired channel

Answer (score 1):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("https://www.youtube.com/"));
            intent.setPackage("com.google.android.youtube");
            PackageManager manager = getPackageManager();
            List<ResolveInfo> info = manager.queryIntentActivities(intent, 0);
            if (info.size() > 0) {
                startActivity(intent);
            } else {
                //No Application can handle your intent
            }
```

This is how u can achieve.. providing only "https://www.youtube.com/" will directly land you into home feed. While one can definitely customize url to redirect to particular channel or video.