# How to perform a Google search in the Google search app programmatically?

Tags: android, android-intent, google-search

[Just like opening a video link in the youtube app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19116727/12980866) (where the programmer needs to specify the app and activity package explicitly). How can I perform a Google search in the Google search app programmatically?

Answer (score -1):

Google offers a public search webservice API which returns JSON: http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/web. Documentation here

Java offers java.net.URL and java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests.

JSON can in Java be converted to a fullworthy Javabean object using an arbitrary Java JSON API. One of the best is Google Gson.

Comment: The link broken and it seems as though nowadays - Aug 2023 - there is no official API. There are 3rd party scrapers that provide API like BeautifulSoup and others.