Android APP URL redirect to Google Play Store instead of opening the App
in my app, have a link to redirect to another app. for example Youtube. i will redirect user to Youtube App using Youtube App Id

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.youtube

however, it will redirect to Google Play Store instead of opening Youtube App. even i have installed the app in my phone. how can i achieve this?

How are you using the Link? Have you tried using an Intent? related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19116634/how-to-open-youtube-app-from-android-application

If you wanted to redirect user to another application installed in the device, you must need to use the LaunchIntentForPackage rather then opening any link that you are doing. You are opening play store link of youtube which obviously redirect user to the play store instead you can use the code below to perform the same
val intent = packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.google.android.youtube")
if (intent != null) {
    // YouTube app is installed, launch it
    startActivity(intent)
} else {
    // YouTube app is not installed, open Play Store
    val playStoreIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.youtube"))
    startActivity(playStoreIntent)
}

If condition will check whether the app where you are redirecting user to is installed in the device or not, if so then it will open the application using application id or package name else it will open the play store link of the provided application.

Use intent, the destination app should accept the URL
this is the "Deep-link"
<activity
    android:name="com.example.android.GizmosActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_gizmos" >
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_view_http_gizmos">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/gizmos” -->
        <data android:scheme="http"
              android:host="www.example.com"
              android:pathPrefix="/gizmos" />
        <!-- note that the leading "/" is required for pathPrefix-->
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_view_example_gizmos">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "example://gizmos” -->
        <data android:scheme="example"
              android:host="gizmos" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

to receive parameters in Activity/Fragment:
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.main)

    val action: String? = intent?.action
    val data: Uri? = intent?.data
}

